# Counter script not counting down

Tags: javascript

I have this counter script but for some reason it isn't working, I'm wondering if you guys can help me! (It is supposed to count downwards)

```
function updateTime() {
  var totalSec = 120;
  var hours = parseInt( totalSec / 3600) % 24;
  var minutes = parseInt( totalSec / 60) % 60;
  var seconds = totalSec % 60;

  var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
  document.getElementById("timeLeft").innerHTML = result;
  totalSec = totalSec - 1;
}

setInterval(function(){ updateTime(); }, 1000);
```

The script turns the totalSec into a format like this: 00:00:00, in this case it's 120 seconds which is 00:02:00, but the script isn't counting down, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var totalSec = 120;` should be outside the function. Your code declares it local and initializes it every time the function is called.

Comment: How did I miss that.. Thank you so much! It's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The function updateTime is being called every second, which means the totalSec variable is being set to 120 each time.

Move that var out of the function. Keep in mind that global vars are a bad idea.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean that global variables are a bad idea?

Comment: Btx is referring to the fact that global variables can be confusing to readers of the code and are in danger of being accidentally overwritten elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delcare `var totalSec=120;` outside of your function.  Your code is working, but every time the function is called it is setting `totalSec` to 120, so you never see any change.